# How can I add the Highscore of the counter?

Tags: javascript, counter, game-engine

I am a beginner and try to code a little game. I have already a counter which shows you the count/ score. I would like to add now a little Highscore for the gamesession. What do I have to add?

```
/* COUNTER */

var onclick = "stopSliding('slider".concat(counter, "','slider", counter+1, "','slider", counter-1, "')");
btn.setAttribute("onclick",onclick);
counter++;
scoreboard.innerHTML = "<p>DEIN SCORE IST <span id='scorecolor'>" + [counter-2] + "!</span></p>";
setRandomColor();
```

Comment: The counter is a high score. You never reset or decrement it.

Comment: if(difference>width||difference<-width){
    document.getElementById("restart").style.display = "block";
    btn.setAttribute("onclick", "");

I am restarting the game with this and it works..

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable. Edit your question. Currently, `counter` is a global variable (in your code snippet). And I don't see where you reset it. If you reset it somewhere, use a second variable with `highscore = Math.max(counter, hightscore);` after `counter++` or in your `reset` function.